# Why does Sweave throw an error on LaTeX code that has been commented out?

Tags: r, sweave

Sweaving the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
<<>>=
x <- 5
y <- 10
@
The value of $z$ is \\
%\Sexpr{z}
\end{document}
```

generates the following error:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'z' not found
Calls: <Anonymous> -> Sweave -> <Anonymous> -> eval -> eval
Execution halted
```

If `\Sexpr{z}` is commented out, why is it causing an error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This answer is a placeholder to record what I learned on my own. I will gladly accept a better one...

Sweave doesn't parse the LaTeX, so it will evaluate any `\Sexpr`, even if it is commented out.  So if you assigned a value to `z` in the code chunk, `%\Sexpr{z}` would print the value of `z`. Amusingly, `\Sexpr{#z}` will suppress the printing of the value of `z`.

I also tracked down [this](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Sweave-processes-Sexpr-in-commented-LaTeX-source-2-3-1patched-and-2-4-0-td912821.html) (rather old) discussion of this issue in a mailing list.

Comment: `%` is the comment character for Tex, not for Sweave. `#` is the comment character for R, but is only understood with in the parsed expressions in the the Sweave environment, ie within `<<>>== ... @` or `\Sexpr{}`